# Can I reduce loss of quality when streching a video? (Sony Vegas)

Tags: video, video-editing, sony-vegas, stretch

I have some very low resolution footage (256x192, 4:3). I stretch it using pan/crop but I keep the aspect ratio. The end result is a 1280x720 with that footage in the middle and personalized side bars to compensate. I'm sure you guys are familiar with that kind of video.
   I already have the project settings set for best rendering quality, good bitrates, deblocking, two pass, high profile, etc...
   I'm wondering if Vegas will use a non-optimal stretching for that footage by default. Can I choose how much post-processing will be done for that stretching and/or which algorithm will be used? Maybe there are filters out there to help with that.

P.s: Those are game recordings btw, in case it is important.

Comment: Only if you work for a police forensics unit in a television show or movie.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, no. The best scaling still duplicates pixels and can't be improved much.

There's things like these but they don't do much IMO.

http://www.makeuseof.com/dir/fixmymovie-enhance-improve-quality-resolution-videos/

More info: http://forum.videohelp.com/threads/226209-Increase-the-resolution-of-a-video

Think about how difficult it would be to go into each image that makes up a video and essentially re-draw the content in more detail - not an easy task.

Your best bet for the future is to record the original in the desired end resolution or higher and process accordingly. [Fraps](http://www.fraps.com/) does great game-related video recording.

Comment: I'm using Dxtory, which is very good. I'm aware that every frame would have to be redrawn, which is pretty drastic. The native resolution for those games I'm mentioning is something I can't change, unfortunately (SNES emulator). Increasing resolution in the emulator just changes the resolution displayed, but not the resolution in the OpenGL process running (To which those recording software hook themselves to).  I was putting my hopes on post-processing for this.

Comment: honestly you may have more luck getting the SNES emulator to do a better scaling job since it is the thing drawing the graphics originally.

Comment: I tried that, but the emulator does the scaling only on what is displaye. It doesn't increase the resolution of the process. Since the recording program hooks to the process, it doesn't make a difference.

Comment: I'm saying get into the emulator code and create a method for scaling up the drawn objects - not easy. You may also have some luck PMing youtube folks who you've seen have higher res SNES videos (if they exist)